# how to access nested object value of axios request's response in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, jsx

i am trying to get category_name of my project_category object from Axios request's response
this is a single record so I am not mapping array its a whole object which stores in my state
this is how i am trying to get that category name

```
const project=this.state.response;

{project.project_category.category_name}
```

here is image of my [image: response]

Comment: This should work fine. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн here is sample
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-fermat-6bimx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: try this.state.response.data.project.project_category.category_name

Comment: @ertemishakk  please check tha above sample link so you can understand this problem

Comment: what output are you expecting? a list or a specific line ?

Comment: So, based on your demo `data.address.street` is not working, right? Even though `Axios.get` is returning correct data.

Comment: Yes, it is not getting the value of street from address object,

Comment: you need to map the data you get from axios, check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is when the component is rendered initially then `this.state.singleProject` is just an empty object and you are trying to access `data.address.street` but this gives an error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

because `data` is an empty object initially.

To fix this issue you can simply use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` that permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid.

So, you can update your template like:

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>{data?.email}</h1>
    <h2>{data?.address?.street}</h2>
  </div>
);
```

and your code will work fine after that.

[image: Edit throbbing-dew-il5dr]

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[],
      singleProject: {},
      errs: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then(res=>{
      this.setState({
        data:res.data
      })
    })
  }
  render() {

    const data = this.state.data;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {data.map(eachData=>(
          <div key={eachData.id}>
            <h1>{eachData.email}</h1>
        <h2>{eachData.address.street}</h2> 
            </div>
        ))}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: yes you are right but in my scenario above answer works fine